# Including templates in Slim v3 MVC

Tags: include, slim

I want to include a template into another, something similar to this:

@include('inc.header')
or
include("inc/header.php");

I'm using Slim framework v3 with slim/php-view

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using `$this` object in the template:

```
<?php
print $name;
print $this->fetch('/inc/header.php');
```

A bit ugly.

From [doc](https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View#templates):

> You may use $this inside your php templates. $this will be the actual
>   PhpRenderer object will allow you to render sub-templates